# Streaming RTSP and RTMP url into azure hosted webapp built in mean stack

Tags: azure-web-app-service, mean-stack, live-streaming, azure-media-services

More details regarding this question

does azure cloud support rtsp live stream url into webapplication hosted in azure cloud setup my web applicaion built in MEAN stack .

any one have suggestion or idea that how i display live rtsp and rtmp stream url directly into azure hosted  web application using html video tag or any other JS libs available to do things....!!

any help regarding this topic is appreciate...

Comment: Directly ingesting an RTSP feed is still a relatively high voted feature request at the Azure Feedback portal. I suggest people wanting this to vote for this [Directly ingesting RTSP](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169396-azure-media-services/suggestions/13560249-directly-ingesting-rtsp) request.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media Services does not currently support RTSP ingest or egress, unfortunately. We don't have a timeline to share on this at the moment. One workaround for ingesting RTSP into Azure Media Services is to use another cloud service provider such as Wowza to re-encode to RTMP.